# What is 10x135 QR?

Tags: wheels, hub

So, just before the standards changed I finished building a very fancy TD bike with 9mm dropouts that I now want a new rear wheel for. I can't seem to find many nice 9mm hubs anymore, but I'm finding wheels that come with a 10x135mm QR.

I'm optimistically hoping that "10x135 QR Included" means I can adapt this hub to fit in my 135mm frame?

What exactly is meant by 10x135mm QR?

[image]

Comment: As a side not, the image you have there has a SRAM XD cassette chosen, just checking you know the difference between cassette bodies and which one you need?

Comment: I'm currently riding an internally geared 11 speed hub, which I like for moderate terrain, but it doesn't have the range I need for steep hills while my bike is loaded with all my bike-packing gear, so I'll be buying a new cassette and derailleur as well.

Comment: Great. Let me know if my answer has answered your question, or whether you think I missed anything.

Comment: @abdnChap Can you adapt pretty much any 12x142 hub with a 10x135 qr?

Comment: Yes and no. Most 12x142 hubs do have their propriatary end caps for converting 10x135. But means you have to have the correct end caps. If you have two hubs, both of which can be converted between 12x142 and 10x135, doesn't necesarily mean the 10x135 caps from one hub will fit in the other hub. Before buying a 12x142 hub, you can do a quick google search or ask a quetion on here "10x135QR End Caps for X hub".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, disc brake mountain bike quick release rear dropouts hold 10mm in diameter axles and are 135mm wide. Most front quick rease front forks take a 9mm axle. So please double check if you do really need 9mm axle on the rear, I doubt it does, but I don't know which bike you have.

10x135QR:

- 10 = 10mm axle diameter
- 135 = 135mm dropout width
- QR = Quick Release

Most non-boost (12x142mm) thru axle hubs can be converted to 10mm 135mm QR.

If the hub says it includes the 10x135QR, then it will fit the starndard 10mm 135 rear dropouts.

Most hubs that have interchanbles end caps are simple to change, see this short [video as an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTNWLisFOP8).

Here is an image with different end caps for Koozer XM490 Hubs (front and rear) which change the spacing of a hub to suit different frames and forks:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The `AI` most likely refers to Cannondale's asymmetric integration. It is very beneficial: the rear of the frame is made asymmetric to make spoke tension on the left and right sides almost equal. However, if your bicycle does not have asymmetry in the rear of the frame, don't buy such a wheel. It will be off-center on your bicycle.

If you don't find a suitable wheel, fear not. Separate hubs are still sold and used. Buy a 36-hole Shimano rear freehub, a good 36-hole rim with sockets ("double eyelets"), and have a professional wheelbuilder build a traditional 36-spoke wheel with high quality butted spokes and brass nipples. It will outlast any machine built wheel you can find on the market.

Comment: I am a professional wheel builder. At least I was when I was still working bike shops. I changed careers prior to when they changed standards and suddenly my bike expertise has become "old school". I'm just not up to speed on the new stuff.